# Need to get data out of a Powershell Object after ConvertFrom-Json

Tags: json, powershell, object

I am doing an API call that is returning a json to my powershell script and is then run through the ConvertFrom-Json function to be a PS object. Some of the fields I'm able to access through `$object.variable` or `$object.variable.subvariable` but there is some nested information that was converted into `System.Objects`.

I am trying to read the information in the `item` `System.Objects` below.

```
item   : @{links=System.Object[]; items=System.Object[]; totalResults=5}
```

When I try `$object.item`, I receive:

```
IsGettable          : True
OverloadDefinitions : {System.Object IList.Item(int index) {get;set;}}
TypeNameOfValue     : System.Object
MemberType          : ParameterizedProperty
Value               : System.Object IList.Item(int index) {get;set;}
Name                : Item
IsInstance          : True
```

I am a novice with powershell so please let me know if any clarification is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **symptom implies** that the **object with the `.item` property is *part of an array***, so you have two options:

- If there's only *one* object whose `.item` property you're interested in, *use its index*; if the array has only one element, use `[0]`:

  ```bash
  $fromJson[0].item

  # To then access the nested .items property:
  $fromJson[0].item.items
  ```
- To get the `.item` property values from *all* objects in your array, use:

  ```bash
  # Fast, but always returns an *array-like* object.
  $fromJson.ForEach('item')

  # To then access the nested .items property:
  $fromJson.ForEach('item').items

  # ---

  # Slower pipeline alternative, behaves like
  # member-access enumeration.
  $fromJson | ForEach-Object item

  # To then access the nested .items property:
  $fromJson | ForEach-Object item | ForEach-Object items
  # OR, with the built-in % alias
  $fromJson | % item | % items
  # OR - given that member-access enumeration does work with .items:
  ($fromJson | ForEach-Object).items
  ```

Note:

- The fact that the nested `.items` property - which is itself array-valued - showed just `System.Object[]`, i.e. just *type* information instead of actual values, is merely a *formatting artifact* that is the result of nesting, as the output from the following nested `[pscustomobject]` demonstrates:

  ```bash
  # ->   item : @{items=System.Object[]}
  [pscustomobject] @{ item = [pscustomobject] @{ items = 1..3 } }
  ```

---

##### Background information:

If the `[pscustomobject]` object graph that is output by a  [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) call happens to be an *array*, trying to access a property on the array that isn't a property of the array object itself results in [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration), i.e. the property access is automatically applied to *each element* of the array, and an array of values is returned.

This means that even if the object happens to be a *single-element* array (possibly unbeknownst to you), you can *normally* still access the property of interest directly on the array; e.g.:

```bash
# Effectively the same as:
#      @([pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1 })[0].foo
@([pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1 }).foo # -> 1
```

However, [`Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.array.system-collections-ilist-item) happens to be the name of a *parameterized property* of [`System.Array`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Array) instances, which underlies *indexed access*.<sup>[1]</sup>

It therefore *takes precedence over member-access enumeration* and - because the property requires an *argument* (the positional index) but wasn't given one - PowerShell prints the *definition* of the parameterized property (the same way it prints the definition of a *method* if you invoke just its name, without an argument list ;e.g.`(42).ToString`).

This is the symptom you saw, and you can easily reproduce it as follows:

```bash
# !! Prints the definition of the array's parameterized .Item property
# !! instead of returning the only element's .item property value.   
@([pscustomobject] @{ item = 'foo' }).item
```

The [intrinsic `.ForEach()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach), as shown above, offers a simple way to avoid such name collisions, because it explicitly accesses the property of the given name *on each element*.

Note, however, that - unlike with member-access enumeration - the result is *always* an array(-like collection), even with only *one* value.<sup>[2]</sup>

The alternative is to use the *pipeline* with the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlet, as also shown above; while slower, it exhibits the same output behavior as member-access enumeration.

---

<sup>[1] Strictly speaking, this property is part of an explicit `IList` interface implementation, but PowerShell surfaces even the members of explicitly implemented faces as direct members of a given type.</sup>

<sup>[2] Member-access enumeration returns a single value as-is, and multiple values as a regular PowerShell array, i.e. typed `[object[]]`. The `.ForEach()` method (as well as `.Where()`) *always* returns an array-like [`[System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[psobject]]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection-1) instance.</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much. This not only helped me solve my problem but really understand what the issue was and how the data was structured.